# New Error in spring boot 2.3.0.RELEASE : UnsatisfiedDependencyException for Oracle 12.2.0.1 jdbcdriver but not with mysql jdbcdriver

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc, spring-data-jdbc

Created a fresh boot project with just jdbc and Oracle jdbc as dependencies

> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
>         <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
>         <version>12.2.0.1</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

I configure the datasource in the application.properties file and run this simple application and it bombs with below stacktrace.

> 2020-05-25 15:07:16.769  WARN 11840 --- [           main]
>   s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'jdbcConverter' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jdbcConverter'
>   parameter 4; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jdbcDialect' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect]: Factory
>   method 'jdbcDialect' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver$NoDialectException:
>   Cannot determine a dialect for
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate@7fe083b1. Please provide a
>   Dialect. 2020-05-25 15:07:16.769  INFO 11840 --- [           main]
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown
>   initiated... 2020-05-25 15:07:17.023  INFO 11840 --- [           main]
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown
>   completed. 2020-05-25 15:07:17.028  INFO 11840 --- [           main]
>   ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
>   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2020-05-25 15:07:17.035
>   ERROR 11840 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication
>   : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'jdbcConverter' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jdbcConverter'
>   parameter 4; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jdbcDialect' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect]: Factory
>   method 'jdbcDialect' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver$NoDialectException:
>   Cannot determine a dialect for
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate@7fe083b1. Please provide a
>   Dialect.  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:539)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
>   [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
>   [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>   [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>   [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
>   [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
>   [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]     at
>   net.sincera.dbmigration.liquibasedemo.LiquibasedemoApplication.main(LiquibasedemoApplication.java:21)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jdbcDialect' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect]: Factory
>   method 'jdbcDialect' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver$NoDialectException:
>   Cannot determine a dialect for
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate@7fe083b1. Please provide a
>   Dialect.  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   ... 19 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect]: Factory
>   method 'jdbcDialect' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver$NoDialectException:
>   Cannot determine a dialect for
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate@7fe083b1. Please provide a
>   Dialect.  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   ... 33 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver$NoDialectException:
>   Cannot determine a dialect for
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate@7fe083b1. Please provide a
>   Dialect.  at
>   org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver.lambda$getDialect$2(DialectResolver.java:76)
>   ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]   at
>   java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290) ~[na:1.8.0_241]     at
>   org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver.getDialect(DialectResolver.java:75)
>   ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.AbstractJdbcConfiguration.jdbcDialect(AbstractJdbcConfiguration.java:144)
>   ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jdbc.JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5730cfab.CGLIB$jdbcDialect$1()
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jdbc.JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5730cfab$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5eb1865b.invoke()
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
>   ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jdbc.JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5730cfab.jdbcDialect()
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_241]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_241]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_241]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_241]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   ... 34 common frames
>   omitted

If I run the above code using spring boot 2.2.7.RELEASE, it works just fine -- No exceptions!!

After 2 days, I thought of configuring a mysql datasource on localhost. The same program runs just fine (with spring boot 2.3.0.RELEASE) but this time it used the mysql datasource.

> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>mysql</groupId>
>         <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
>         <scope>runtime</scope>
>     </dependency>
> ```

What is happening with the oracle jdbc driver in spring boot 2.3.0.RELEASE ?

What is mysql jdbc driver doing correctly in spring boot 2.3.0.RELEASE ?

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that Spring Data JDBC does not provide a dialect for Oracle out of the box. See [Spring Data JDBC Firebird dialect not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61851491/spring-data-jdbc-firebird-dialect-not-recognized) for a solution (though you'll need to modify it to work for Oracle).

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel : thanks very much. I pinged you on that post. How can spring data jdbc 2.0 provide a dialect for mysql but not provide for oracle -- did suddenly spring come to recognize that they don't want to support the very popular oracle out of the box ? OR is that an oversight ?

Comment: I don't know, you should ask the maintainers for Spring Data JDBC that question.

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel, thank you. I've tweeted them. Hoping to hear from them after the holiday.

Comment: **Note:** this problem only affects Spring Boot versions `2.3.x`. `2.2.x` worked seamlessly because there was no strict `Dialect` facility yet. `2.4.x` once again works OOTB, because [official support](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-relational/issues/478) for the `OracleDialect` was added in Spring Data JDBC 2.1, which in turn, is referenced by Boot versions `2.4.0` and up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What is happening with the oracle jdbc driver in spring boot 2.3.0.RELEASE ?

The JDBC Driver is doing just fine.

As you already learned in the comments the problem is that

a) Spring Data JDBC now requires a `Dialect` for each database

b) Spring Data JDBC does not ship with a `Dialect` for Oracle.

### The fix:

As described in [Spring Data JDBC Firebird dialect not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61851491/spring-data-jdbc-firebird-dialect-not-recognized) and in https://spring.io/blog/2020/05/20/migrating-to-spring-data-jdbc-2-0
you need to provide your own `Dialect` implementation right now.

Something like this should work:

```
class MyOracleDialect extends AnsiDialect {

    private static final LimitClause LIMIT_CLAUSE = new LimitClause() {

        @Override
        public String getLimit(long limit) {
            return String.format("FETCH NEXT %d ROWS ONLY", limit);
        }

        @Override
        public String getOffset(long offset) {
            return String.format("OFFSET %d ROWS", offset);
        }

        @Override
        public String getLimitOffset(long limit, long offset) {
            return String.format("OFFSET %d ROWS FETCH NEXT %d ROWS ONLY", offset, limit);
        }

        @Override
        public Position getClausePosition() {
            return Position.AFTER_ORDER_BY;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public LimitClause limit() {
        return LIMIT_CLAUSE;
    }

}
```

You then need to make the `Dialect` available via a `DialectProvider` as described in the referenced Stackoverflow question:

### Some background:

So far the Spring Data team does not run their integration tests with an Oracle database.
This is because for quite some time it was unclear how to do that in a legal way since all the code including the build infrastructure was open source and Oracle required accepting of all kinds of stuff to use a database instance or their driver.

By now Docker images are available for testing and the JDBC driver is available from Maven Central. It is still a little tricky since the current options for docker images that I am aware of let you choose between an image size of many GBs or a start up time of about 15 minutes.

Anyway there is a community member working on the issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-256

I'm therefore confident that we will be able to fully support Oracle in the near future.

Comment: As far as I know, Oracle supports the SQL standard OFFSET/FETCH syntax (see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlqr/Subclauses.html#GUID-3DBA60BC-0822-43B4-B332-17C170C79304)), so it should be possible to use `AnsiDialect` without replacing the limit clause.

Comment: @JensSchauder, thank you for the detailed explanation. But my expectation of spring and more so of spring boot is that things work out of the box for most common stuff. And a lot of enterprise applications run on Oracle db even today. Come on, Oracle, please work with spring to make Oracle DB and Java developers' life easier. We know that you have developers's good in your heart!

Comment: @JensSchauder : I see that the issue is in RESOLVED state as of May. What's preventing Oracle from being used in the integration tests ?

Comment: @anjanb The issue was resolved in July. And the main problems we had are described in the "Some background" section of the answer.

Answer (score 10):

This Dialect resolver fixed my issue with Oracle.

```
 @Configuration
   public class SpringDataJdbcConfiguration extends AbstractJdbcConfiguration {
    
        @Override
        public Dialect jdbcDialect(NamedParameterJdbcOperations operations) {
            return AnsiDialect.INSTANCE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Simple yet elegant not sure why this is not fixed yet

Answer (score 2):

Currently spring data jdbc doesn't support oracle dialect
You need to define your own dialect resolver
Add following class for Oracle Dialect which implements `JdbcDialectProvider`.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver.JdbcDialectProvider;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.AnsiDialect;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.ConnectionCallback;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations;

public class OracleDialectResolver implements JdbcDialectProvider {

    @Override
    public Optional<Dialect> getDialect(JdbcOperations operations) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(operations.execute((ConnectionCallback<Dialect>) OracleDialectResolver::getDialect));
    }

    private static Dialect getDialect(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        DatabaseMetaData metaData = connection.getMetaData();
        String name = metaData.getDatabaseProductName().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
        if (name.contains("oracle")) {
            return AnsiDialect.INSTANCE;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Register your provider by putting a file `spring.factories` in the `META-INF` folder of your class path and add the following line.

```
org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver$JdbcDialectProvider=com.mypackage.jdbctemplate.dialect.OracleDialectResolver //fuly qualified class name of your dialect resolver class
```

Comment: thank you. Would you know why ? The answer above mentions that it's because Oracle DB is currently not easily made available for unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem last week.

The change I did in my project was simpler: I just replaced HikariCP dependency with tomcat-jdbc in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    <!-- HikariCP doesn't deals with jdbcDialect properly -->
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <!-- Dependency removed -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dependency to tomcat-jdbc to deal with jdbcDialect -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--...-->
```

If I undo this, the exception you posted in title happens again.

Good luck for you.

Comment: Thanks @user3634250.. Given the answer from above, how does your solution work for a spring data jdbc application ?

Answer (score 1):

small update to the already posted answer, for oracle Dialect
in
**Build.gradle**

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-relational', version: '2.1.1'
```

and then create below class

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.AbstractJdbcConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.OracleDialect;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcOperations;

@Configuration
public class SpringDataJdbcConfiguration extends AbstractJdbcConfiguration {

  @Override
  public Dialect jdbcDialect(NamedParameterJdbcOperations operations) {
    return OracleDialect.INSTANCE;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These dependencies worked for me.

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
  </dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
  <version>19.6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nirmala. But we're not using Oracle 19.x -- we're using Oracle 12 and 11 -- not sure if using a later version of ojdbc.jar will work.

Comment: Your are using 2.2.6.RELEASE and the thread is related to 2.3.x.RELEASE ...

Answer (score -2):

This configuration works well in my setup.

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>

</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

public class Demo {
    private static String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:user/pass@localhost:1521/XEPDB1";

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.out.print( "Testing connection to database ..." );

        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            System.out.println("OK");
            System.exit(0); // Prevent hang after completion when ran by mvn
        } catch (SQLException ignore) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + ignore);
            System.exit(1); // Prevent hang after completion when ran by mvn
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't use Spring Data JDBC.

Comment: Thanks but I need to use spring data jdbc stuff like JdbcTemplate, etc. Not plain jdbc.